# How to calculate working days on ORACLE APEX?

Tags: oracle-apex

I have 2 tables; employee and time. For time table, I want to take id information automatically from employee table and subtracting every employees' start date of work from employee table from system date. If result = 1 year plus, result will be automatically added to the time table.

employee.hire_date **date** /
time.year **number**

I want it to do this **(time.year = sysdate - employee.hire_date)** process automatically.

For example, the employee started on 21.01.2019. Today(21.01.2020) write **'1'** on time table year column automatically.

Thanks.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include a [MRE] with: DDL statements for the two tables; DML statements for some sample data in the "different" table; your expected output; and details of "how" you expect it to be updated daily (trigger on the different table, scheduled job, the table isn't actually a table but a view or a materialized view, etc.). Please help us to help you by providing us with enough information to answer the question and by giving us your existing progress to work with.

Comment: I have 2 tables; employee and time. For time table, I want to take id information automatically from employee table and subtracting every employees' start date of work from employee table from system date. If result = 1 year plus, result will be automatically added to the time table.

Comment: Don't post details into a comment; [edit] your question. Also, please provide more details: DDL statements with columns and data types; DML statements with example data; details of the method with which you want it to automatically update; and so on.

Answer (score 0):

Create `times` as a view on the `employees` table.

**Oracle Setup**:

```sql
CREATE TABLE employees ( id, start_date ) AS
SELECT 1, DATE '2019-01-21' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, DATE '2019-06-21' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 3, DATE '2015-01-01' FROM DUAL;
```

**Create View**:

```sql
CREATE VIEW times ( id, years ) AS
SELECT id,
       FLOOR( MONTHS_BETWEEN( SYSDATE, start_date ) / 12 )
FROM   employees;
```

**Output**:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   times;
```

gives:

> ```
> ID | YEARS
> -: | ----:
>  1 |     1
>  2 |     0
>  3 |     5
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=f1b72036aa05dce3f47b9e977c83d2d4)*